# how to search and replace a block in files with Eclipse or PowerGREP?

Tags: regex, linux, windows, eclipse, powergrep

There is a **read me** section at the beginning of my files, many files. The section's format likes this:

```
###############   Read me ###############

many lines here

########################################
```

I want to update them with new contents. I am using **Windows 7** but has access to **Linux**. I have **Eclipse** and also **PowerGREP**.  I don't know how to do this with OS command line commands, and also don't know how to use Eclipse or PowerGREP to do this. Anybody can help me about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If format of your sections is always the same, it should be as easy as this:

```
###############   Read me ###############[\s\S]*?########################################
```

With an inline `(?s)` single-line/dot-matches-all mode you could use a regular `.` instead of `[\s\S]` but it doesn't matter much. See the [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2HtcwZ/1).

Then, replace the text block as needed.

Comment: since you got a -1 even if your answer is good +1! ;-) I don't know there is someone who really like to downvote everyone... `jww` or someone else... got downvoted too... :(

Comment: Have tested several different combinations: yours works, yours without '?' also works.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily with `awk`

**INPUT:**

```
###############   Read me ###############

many lines here
many lines here
many lines here

########################################
real stuff
real stuff
real stuff
real stuff
###############   Read me ###############

many lines here
many lines here
many lines here
blabla

########################################
real stuff2
real stuff2
real stuff2
```

**command:**

```
awk '/######   Read me #####/{a=0}/^#+$/{a=1;next}{if(a)print}' input
real stuff
real stuff
real stuff
real stuff
real stuff2
real stuff2
real stuff2
```

You just need to redirect the output to another file.

**Explanations:**

- `/######   Read me #####/{a=0}` when the lines contain `######   Read me #####` put a variable at `0`
- `/^#+$/{a=1;next}` when a line contains only `#` put that variable back to `1`
- `{if(a)print}` when the variable is at `1` print the line